# Run two servers simultanually from bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have two servers that I need to run with these commands:

```
cd /home/hadoop/apache-hive-3.1.1-bin/ 
sudo hiveserver2
```

and

```
sudo /opt/hue/build/env/bin/hue runserver
```

So I putted both commands in a **script.sh** (along with other stuff):

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-yarn.sh
cd /home/hadoop/apache-hive-3.1.1-bin/ 
hiveserver2 & 
sudo /opt/hue/build/env/bin/hue runserver &
```

So when I execute it with `bash script.sh` only the four first lines work. The hue server never get urned on.

Why is that ? Is it because the terminal stays reserved for the hiveserver?
How can I avoid that please. Thank you

---

**EDIT 1:**

So, I edited as suggested my script:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-yarn.sh
sudo gnome-terminal -- bash -c "cd /home/hadoop/apache-hive-3.1.1-bin; hiveserver2 &" 
sudo /opt/hue/build/env/bin/hue runserver &
```

and I executed using `bash script.sh`. Now hueserver is running but not hiveserver. A second terminal is open but with nothing in it (total black screen).

Comment: Sorry but same problem persists.

Comment: Please check edited question. Thank you

Comment: Now it only executes first two lines then it asks for user's password without a prompt so i can type it (It just prints [sudo] enter hadoop password: and it exits without waiting for me to put the password)

Comment: Because otherwise I'll get the following error after the first two lines: No protocol specified
unable to init server could not connect connection refused

Comment: I should probably precise that it isn't my main user that executes the script. Actually before executing it I need to do: su - hadoop and enter hadoop password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what you can do instead :

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh; $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-yarn.sh; cd /home/hadoop/apache-hive-3.1.1-bin; hiveserver2" &&
sudo /opt/hue/build/env/bin/hue runserver &
```

Comment: Now it runs first two commands and then:  No protocol specified unable to init server could not connect connection refused

Comment: I should probably precise that it isn't my main user that executes the script. Actually before executing it I need to do: su - hadoop and enter hadoop password

Comment: I still had the same problem using the script in your answer (No protocol specified unable to init server could not connect connection refused ) so I added sudo before gnome-* and now it opens a new terminal, executes the first two commands (start-dfs and start-yarn) and then it closes and in the main terminal it runs hue. hiveserver still not activated

Comment: When I execute separtely separately the hue or hive servers I actually need to leave the terminal open otherwise it will stop the running servers. I need a way to keep the scond terminal (the one that get launched with gnome-terminal) open